# How to use Filterable in ListAdapter using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I would use a `SearchView` to filter my `RecyclerView`, on stackoverflow and other sites i've found just examples of using `Filterable` with Java and with `RecyclerView.Adapter` while i'm using `ListAdapter`..

So i was trying to make the custom filter by my self but when i try to filter the adapter i just get a null on my `MutableList` in `publishResults`.

My **Adapter** code looks like this:

```
class ArticoliListAdapter : ListAdapter<Articolo, ArticoliListAdapter.ArticoliViewHolder>(ArticoliComparator()), Filterable {
    private val list = mutableListOf<Articolo>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticoliViewHolder {
        return ArticoliViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticoliViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current)
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        val articolo = currentList[position]
        return articolo.barcode.hashCode().toLong()
    }




    class ArticoliViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val barcode: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.barcode)
        private val qta: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qta)
        private val desc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc)
        private val um: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.um)
        fun bind(articolo: Articolo?) {
            barcode.text = articolo?.barcode
            qta.text = articolo?.qta?.formatForQta()
            um.text = articolo?.um?.toLowerCase(Locale.ITALIAN)
            desc.text = if(articolo?.desc.isNullOrEmpty()) "-" else articolo?.desc
        }

        private fun Float.formatForQta(): String {
            val floatString = this.toString()
            val decimalString: String = floatString.substring(floatString.indexOf('.') + 1, floatString.length)
            return when (decimalString.toInt() == 0) {
                true -> this.toInt().toString()
                false -> "%.3f".format(this)
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): ArticoliViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
                return ArticoliViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class ArticoliComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Articolo>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Articolo, newItem: Articolo): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Articolo, newItem: Articolo): Boolean {
            return oldItem.qta == newItem.qta
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return customFilter
    }

    private val customFilter = object: Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filteredList = mutableListOf<Articolo>()
            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()){
                filteredList.addAll(currentList)
            }else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ITALIAN).trim { it <= ' ' }
                for (item in currentList) {
                    if (item.barcode.toLowerCase(Locale.ITALIAN).contains(filterPattern) || item.desc?.toLowerCase(
                            Locale.ITALIAN
                        )!!.contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            val results = FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults?) {
            list.clear()
            list.addAll(filterResults?.values as MutableList<Articolo>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

}
```

So i was wondering which would be the right way to built a custom filter to filter my data in the recyclerView by using ListAdapter in Kotlin.

I'm calling the filter in my fragment like this:

```
    override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
        adapter.filter.filter(query)
        return false
    }
```

But when i try to filter nothing happend and still all items are shown...

Data to the `RecyclerView` adapter is set from my `ViewHolder` and the data is get from the DataBase (`LiveData<List<Articolo>>`)

Here is the code from my Fragment:

```
   articoliViewModel.articoli.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { articoli ->
        articoli.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
    }
```

Comment: What is `currentList` here ? i don't see the declaration

Comment: @ADM currentList here is (Mutable)List<Articolo!> (currentList equals to getCurrentList) the data to the adapter is set via LiveData get from database

Comment: Don't use filterable! It's unnecessary complication and boilerplate code. Just use regular filter method. Inside onquerytextchanged adapter.submitList(list.filter{...})

Comment: Those answers that you saw were probably on java. I myself once answered by suggesting to use filterable, but it was a mistake. Even if you use java its it possible to create kotlin class with filtering function and use in java code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Few flaws in your code which i am listing down below.

1. `currentList` is holding the current items which r on list not the complete list of items . i.e if you have 10 items and after filter u get 3 items then `currentList` will be holding 3 items not 10 . So you can not use `currentList` for filtering the list . instead u hold on to the `CompleteList` and apply filter on this one .
2. you should not be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` this just defeats the whole purpose of having `DiffUtils`, instead you call `#submitList`
3. Al thought you have a reference to complete list as global variable but you have never assigned value to it its always empty.

I have made a working sample to illustrate. pls try same with your code adding the essential code below. I have use type as `String` just to make sample easy to understand you can use your custom object. You can also modify the code to make it look better but i think its enough to get the idea how `ListAdapter` works.

```
class ArticoliListAdapter : ListAdapter<String, ArticoliListAdapter.ArticoliViewHolder>(ArticoliComparator()), Filterable {
    private var list = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticoliViewHolder {
        return ArticoliViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticoliViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current)
    }

    fun setData(list: MutableList<String>?){
        this.list = list!!
        submitList(list)
    }

    class ArticoliViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val desc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName)
        fun bind(name: String) {
            desc.text = name.toUpperCase()
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): ArticoliViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
                return ArticoliViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class ArticoliComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return customFilter
    }

    private val customFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filteredList = mutableListOf<String>()
            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(list)
            } else {
                for (item in list) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            val results = FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults?) {
            submitList(filterResults?.values as MutableList<String>)
        }

    }
}
```

When you set data to adapter you call `setData` not `submitList`.

```
articoliViewModel.articoli.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { articoli ->
    articoli.let { adapter.setData(it) }
}
```

Comment: in my SearchView how should i call the Filter?

Comment: Same way adapter.getfilter().filter("text").

Comment: okay seems i made it work, but how can i reset the list when searchView is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Correct my if I'm wrong, but I would say that there's a mistake here:

```
  override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults?) {
            list.clear()
            list.addAll(filterResults?.values as MutableList<Articolo>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

I would do the following:

```
  override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults?) {
            list.clear()
            list.addAll(filterResults?.values as MutableList<Articolo>)
            submitList(list)
        }
```