# Why filtering property not work for search bar in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

I have a simple android project, there is a recycler view in fragment for user list, and I want to use search bar for those users, that is why I am using filtering for search the user in list view, everything is work but when I search user name, nothing change, and filtering property not work for users name. Any idea will be appreciated.

**GameAdapter:**

```
class GameAdapter(
    private val userId: String,
      var chatList: ArrayList<Game>

): RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.GamesHolder>(), Filterable {

    private var clickListener: ClickListener? = null
        var filteredUserDataList: MutableList<Game>

    inner class GamesHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        val textGameTitle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textUsername)
     
    }
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GamesHolder, position: 
   Int) {
    val game = filteredUserDataList[position]
  holder.textGameTitle.text = 
 game.getGameName(userId).toString()
    }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return filteredUserDataList.size
}
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return filter
}

private var filter = object : Filter() {

    override fun performFiltering(keyword: CharSequence): FilterResults {
        val filtereddata = java.util.ArrayList<Game>()
        if (keyword.toString().isEmpty()) filtereddata.addAll(gameList) else {
            for (obj in gameList) {
                if (obj.getGameName(userId).toLowerCase()
                        .contains(keyword.toString().toLowerCase())
                ) filtereddata.add(obj)
            }
        }
        val results = FilterResults()
        results.values = filtereddata
        return results
    }

  
    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
        gameList.clear()
        gameList.addAll((results.values as ArrayList<Game>))
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    init {
        filteredUserDataList = gameList
    }
}

fun getItem(index: Int): Game {
    return filteredUserDataList[index]
}
```

**GameFragment:**

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var recyclerViewGame: RecyclerView

    var searchView: EditText? = null
    var search: CharSequence = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false)

        recyclerViewGame = view.findViewById(R.id.game_list)

        configureRecycler(gameList)

        return view

    }

    private fun configureRecycler(games: ArrayList<Game>) {
        val userId = userPresenter.getGame().id
        val gamesAdapter = context?.let {
            GameAdapter(userId, it, games)
        }

        searchView = view?.findViewById(R.id.search_bar)

        searchView?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                gamesAdapter.filter.filter(charSequence)
                search = charSequence
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
        })
     } }
```

Comment: `if (row.participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                                .contains(Key.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))) {` is a condition that probably won't match.. have you tried it with a simpler one?

Comment: @Zain, I am using the username instead of the "iparticipants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username", it says "Unresolved reference: username", any idea?

Comment: What `Key` refers to.. is that the searched user name?

Comment: @Zain, ı update question

Comment: Your adapter is bit messed up . you are making change in `filteredUserDataList` inside `publishResults` while your `getItemCount` returns `gameList.size` ..  have a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021760/4168607) i tried to explain it there . there are lots of answers on this topic but i can't find the exact one . So here you go ..

Comment: @ADM, I update question according to ur answer, but still same, I do not know ,I miss whats

Comment: @ADM, I am try it since 2 days, but not solve, can u help me, where I miss, and what is my mistake, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see these things

1. filteredUserDataList should be initialized with gameList
2. change

   override fun getItemCount() = gameList.size

   to

   override fun getItemCount() = filteredUserDataList.size
3. and remember that filteredUserDataList is the main list and the actual
   gameList is just to maintain the original data if the user clears or change the search query

Comment: tnx so much but it is not work, I guess, maybe I can use username instead  of the participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username, but how?

Comment: I have to use   override fun getItemCount() = gameList.size

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return filteredUserDataList.size
    } both of them, maybe it will help me, but how can I use both altogether

Comment: @Skysoft13 you can overide a method only once and this is the correct overiding 
override fun getItemCount(): Int { return filteredUserDataList.size }

Comment: yes u are right, ı do it but still same not filter, ı do not get it, where is mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have check for `userName` not the `userId`. This is bit confusing for me because you are using `userId` inside predicate and `userId` is a global field in your case . I do not understand the role of `userId` here  .

Anyway i am adding a solution below based on what i understood. give it a try

```
override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val searchTerm = charSequence.toString().lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
            filteredUserDataList = if(searchTerm.isEmpty()){
                gameList
            }else{
                val lstFiltered: ArrayList<Game> = ArrayList()
                for (row in gameList) {
                    val user = row.participants.find {
                        it.username.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchTerm)
                    }
                    if (user!=null) {
                        lstFiltered.add(row)
                    }
                }
                lstFiltered
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = filteredUserDataList
            return filterResults
        }

 override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: FilterResults) {
            filteredUserDataList = filterResults.values as ArrayList<Game>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

In case if you are trying to search by two fields `username` and `userId` so you have to consider both when applying filter .

Comment: tnx for ur respond, I want to use username, that is why I used the getGameName(userId), because there is not username in Game model, is there any other solution  for username pls :)